# Uploading a CSV file, distorted characters

Tags: postgresql

I am having a problem when uploading a csv file through the following query,

```
COPY adwords_initial("Account",
"Week",
"Campaign",
"Keyword",
"Ad group",
"Keyword state",
"Match type",
"Max. CPC",
"Clicks",
"Impressions",
"Cost",
"Avg. position",
"Ad group state",
"Campaign state",
"Status",
"Qual. score (hist.)",
"Expected clickthrough rate (hist.)",
"Ad relevance (hist.)",
"Landing page experience (hist.)",
"First page CPC",
"First position CPC",
"Top of page CPC",
"Bounce rate","Pages / session",
"Avg. session duration (seconds)",
"% new sessions",
"Search Exact match IS",
"Search Lost IS (rank)",
"Search Impr. share",
"Conversions",
"Conv. rate") 
FROM 'C:\Users\iantu\Desktop\Performance Marketing\Report inputs\input.csv' 
 DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER encoding 'windows-1251';
```

Characters in French do not translate accordingly as an example

```
in keyword the original file has  +connectivité +IoT
in keyword the postgresql file has  +connectivitÐ¹ +IoT
```

Do settings have to be changed within my application?

I should also mention that I then export this using the following query, however, the data as can be seen is already corrupted within the database.

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM adwords_initial) TO 'C:\Users\iantu\Desktop\Performance Marketing\Report Outputs\in between workflow.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: Have you tried `latin1` instead of `windows-1251`? Tried adding `NULL as E''`?

Comment: How are you getting the data back? It may be just fine in the database

Comment: latin1 worked like a charm, cheers mate.

Comment: @IanJames would you mind accepting it as an answer if I post it as one?

Comment: Sure, go right ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `latin1` as encoding:

```
COPY adwords_initial("Account",
"Week",
"Campaign",
"Keyword",
"Ad group",
"Keyword state",
"Match type",
"Max. CPC",
"Clicks",
"Impressions",
"Cost",
"Avg. position",
"Ad group state",
"Campaign state",
"Status",
"Qual. score (hist.)",
"Expected clickthrough rate (hist.)",
"Ad relevance (hist.)",
"Landing page experience (hist.)",
"First page CPC",
"First position CPC",
"Top of page CPC",
"Bounce rate","Pages / session",
"Avg. session duration (seconds)",
"% new sessions",
"Search Exact match IS",
"Search Lost IS (rank)",
"Search Impr. share",
"Conversions",
"Conv. rate") 
FROM 'C:\Users\iantu\Desktop\Performance Marketing\Report inputs\input.csv' 
 DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER encoding 'latin1';
```